# Maxent error: Error projecting, two layers have different geographic dimensions

Tags: land-use, maxent

When I run climate data (signed 16 bit) and land use data (unsigned 8 bit) on  Maxent, I got an error message:

> Error projecting: java.io.IOException: Files bio6 and alt in directory
>   D:\WorldClim\Future\ACCESS1_0\rcp4 have different geographic
>   dimensions.

Despite correcting the layers to have the same dimensions (I AOI of the same), Maxent still gives me an error message for the same two layers.

Comment: I'm guessing here. Are these vector or raster files? If raster, do they use the same cell size? Looking online, someone said that in addition to same cell size and extent, that the rasters should be 'snapped' so that the cells/extent start at the same location.

Comment: The error points to `bio6` and `alt` (altitude) layers (not `land-use`), or I don't get the role of land use data in your question :). Can you add some info about layers in error e.g. from `gdal info` command line or QGIS raster info function?